# How to get the video thumbnail from tune.pk video from the video id of that video like in youtube?

Tags: php, jquery, html, video, youtube

How to get the video thumbnail from tune.pk video from the video id of that video like in youtube?
for youtube i use

```
<code>
    <img class="video-thumbnail" 
    src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<?php echo $video_id; ?>/0.jpg" alt="" width="190">
</code>
```

where

`$video_id` is the code of that video from `url`.

Can I do something similar for tune.pk videos

Comment: I misunderstood yorr question and posted an answer for youtube, sry about that. You'll need to write a custom script for tune.pk, because the images url looks like this `http://storage8.gear3rd.net/files/thumbs/2013/12/01/1385926403297e4-1.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the YouTube URL format that you will need in order to view and download a thumbnail from a YouTube video:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/VIDEO_ID/#.jpg
```

… where for the video example above, `VIDEO_ID=bQVoAWSP7k4` and `#` (`1,2, or 3`) corresponds to one of the 3 thumbnails that YouTube automatically generates.

`#2`, is the default thumbnail, or the one that the owner ends up choosing for their video.

Using this convention, below are the URLs and the thumbnails that I was able to pull off of YouTube for the "wedding proposal" video from Jeremy's post.

**1st Thumbnail Image, Small (120×90)**
http://img.youtube.com/vi/bQVoAWSP7k4/1.jpg

[image: http://img.youtube.com/vi/bQVoAWSP7k4/1.jpg]

**2nd | Default Thumbnail Image, Small (120×90)**
http://img.youtube.com/vi/bQVoAWSP7k4/2.jpg

[image: http://img.youtube.com/vi/bQVoAWSP7k4/2.jpg]

**3rd Thumbnail Image, Small (120×90)**
http://img.youtube.com/vi/bQVoAWSP7k4/3.jpg

[image: http://img.youtube.com/vi/bQVoAWSP7k4/3.jpg]

**Default Thumbnail Image, Full-Size (480×360)**
http://img.youtube.com/vi/bQVoAWSP7k4/0.jpg

[image: http://img.youtube.com/vi/bQVoAWSP7k4/0.jpg]

I hope helps.